# Limbs where muscle composition is 90% fast-glycolytic and 10% slow-oxidative. Would it be too specialized to be practical?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, creature-design

So, many predators, but especially felines, have more "strength" per kilogram than humans. Why? Well, it's in the type of muscle fiber they use.

These types are:

1. Slow-oxidative: Small force production, very high endurance, found in skeletal muscles responsible for posture.
2. Fast-oxidative: Medium force production, medium endurance. Found everywhere in skeletal muscles
3. Fast-glycolytic: Very-high force production, low endurance.

Now, these are somewhat loose categories, as they're the result of tweaking the ratio of onboard oxygen reserves (myoglobin) and actual myosin chains. More reserves decrease the density of myosin, but lets muscles use aerobic respiration, which is efficient. Without reserves, you can put in more "engines", but they will have to rely on inefficient anaerobic respiration, making them tire quicker.

So, what is my context?

Well, there is a handful of genetically-engineered creatures in my setting that were designed with modern combat in mind, but in a way that doesn't violate the Geneva Convention. So, they aren't as extreme as mobile balls of slime that turn into airborne *[Yersinia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yersinia_pestis)* when pulverized by gunfire.

On paper they have differences, but all of them are agile and flexible quadrupeds that have human intelligence and are capable of communicating with humans.

Their primary purpose is to help SEALs (well, this setting's equivalent of them) move through rough terrain such as mountains and dense forests. They have a limited carrying capacity, due to their [floating shoulders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_anatomy#Skeleton), but can be equipped with lighter grenade launchers that go right on their backs.

Their limbs are supposed to have a muscle fiber composition of 90-95% fast-glycolytic and 10-5% slow oxidative fibers. The reason is to give them sprint bursts to help with darting from cover to cover, along with melee strikes that could kill fully armored people through sheer force (shake up their brains a bit).

However, I'm not sure if this is the best idea. **Would such high fractions of fast-glycolytic muscle fibers inevitably reduce the creatures' stamina and/or structural integrity (remember, floating shoulders) to the point where they can't be used as intended?**

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking about these creatures being used mainly as mounts, right? Possibly acting as a supply transport or as attack animal as a secondary use?

Comment: @Redbud201 Well, supply transport over short but difficult treks and weapon platform as a secondary use.

Answer (score 3):

The main purpose of your creature is to act as a pack animal across difficult terrain. More or less, all currently popular pack animals lean towards strength and endurance rather than bursts of speed. Humans are endurance walkers and runners, so the animals we use for packing have to keep up.

A feline bone and muscle structure, as compared to horses, mules, etc, is not well suited for carrying loads on its back at all, and the proportions of muscle fibers you are talking about are not really suited for carrying loads for extended periods. Felines are great stealthy and fast predators though.

But there is a caveat: If the pack animal has human intelligence and is faster by a large margin than the humans on foot, it can move supplies on its own in advance of the unit, and not alongside a squad of humans which would just slow it down. This type of operation might suit such a burst-running creature better, moving at their own pace.

If you want your creature to be a pack carrier that sticks with the squad, I would actually suggest that you make two specialized creatures, one based on any number of hooved animals like mules and goats, for carrying supplies in difficult terrain, and another as stealthy and fast attack animal. The two purposes are almost contradictory. Horses and dogs probably have the highest endurance of any "fast" animals. Most others are short range sprinters.

Now that's just building off of existing animals. (Floating shoulders are not good for load bearing, as you seem to know). As for muscle composition, we can do something interesting. Humans have mostly endurance "slow-twitch" fibers, but the release of adrenaline and epinephrine changes the function of those slow-twitch fibers to increase their contraction speed and be able to temporarily use anerobic glycotic energy from what I understand. This allows humans to increase their power output roughly 50-100%. Whereas many animals have this strength to call upon all the time, humans have endurance muscles most of the time, and "pseudo fast-twitch" muscles in times of great stress, which let's us "cheat the system" so to speak, to be able to get power when needed and endurance as the norm. (This does correspond to a slight loss of fine motor functions though.)

[Side tangent: For energy storage, you might be able to engineer a more efficient tissue than fat for something that could act as a reservoir for energy. Something that can disperse compounds into the blood more quickly, which is where the glucose the muscles use is usually stored, as I understand.]

Finally, it's worth pointing out that glycotic/anerobic muscle use comes with a heavy cost of inefficient use of energy and byproducts building up in the tissue. This seems to be a problem that can be solved with genetic engineering.

Take the case of marathon runner Dean Karazes. So the main chemical build up from glycotic muscle use is lactate and lactic acid, which causes problems in high concentrations. It can cause muscle cramping and pain if it builds up too much and is a factor in endurance. Certain mitochondrial processes can reconvert this lactate back into glucose. But this man seems to have un-ordinarily high tolerances for the chemical, essentially having muscles that just don't tire out. There is also possibly a nervous system adaptation to ignore pain as well, which would be a good thing to give to your creature.

I wish I had a proper source for the adrenaline changing the way the muscles function, but I'm out of time and I'll have to wrap this up here. I hope this information is of some use to you. Anybody who is an expert in the field, feel free to add clarifications or corrections in the comments.

[https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/the-running-blog/2013/aug/30/dean-karnazes-man-run-forever#:~:text=Most%20runners%20have%20to%20stop,days%20and%20nights%20without%20stopping](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/the-running-blog/2013/aug/30/dean-karnazes-man-run-forever#:%7E:text=Most%20runners%20have%20to%20stop,days%20and%20nights%20without%20stopping).